# How to understand QEBEK (Honeypot Monitoring Tool)?

Tags: monitoring, honeypot

I've been trying for some time to find recent or meaningful documentation regarding QEBEK, but all I've found is the [Intro](https://www.honeynet.org/project/Qebek) and [KYT Paper for Installation 2010](https://www.honeynet.org/sites/default/files/files/KYT-Qebek-final_v1.pdf). The links are just a formal introduction, and a very old installation guide (which unfortunately doesn't seem to work). I'd like to know what happened with QEBEK, since it's now about five years after the release of the KYT paper linked above.

According to the KYT paper, it was the only open-source high-interaction honeypot monitoring tool. Since I'm new to the field, I may be missing something, but can anyone shed any light on this? Is there an open-source alternative to QEBEK?

Update: I've posted this same question on the [Project Honeypot](http://www.projecthoneypot.org/board/read.php?f=4&i=1243&t=1243) forum.

Answer (score 1):

Not to nitpick, but it sounds as though you're interested in honeypots/honeynets in general. There are several honeypot [solutions](https://www.honeynet.org/project) available. The aforementioned are open source and easily accessible, documented and will aid you in your projects. Also, the honeynet project brought you Quebek but has several honeypots that are based off of bochs/qemu.

Comment: Qebek is a HI honeypot other than Sebek, other solutions like dionaea, Kippo etc are low interaction so I am concerned with Qebek. That would be great if you can share about any HI Honeypot other than Sebek or about Qebek. Thanks